# Complicated Date Join: Need most recent date entry per group occurring before the date entry from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join, merge

I've come across a join in SQL I seem unable to wrap my head around the mechanics of. To start, I have these 2 tables:

Table 1:

```
ClientID | Date         | Value
---------|--------------|------
63       | 2019-10-04   | 77
63       | 2019-10-05   | 50
63       | 2019-10-06   | 70
63       | 2019-10-07   | 62
67       | 2019-10-04   | 64
67       | 2019-10-05   | 69
67       | 2019-10-06   | 66
```

Table 2:

```
ClientID | Date         | Target
---------|--------------|------
63       | 2019-10-04   | 80
63       | 2019-10-06   | 55
67       | 2019-10-04   | 65
67       | 2019-10-07   | 70
```

Essentially, I'd like to join the most recent 'target' per Client from table 2 to the values in table 1. This way I can track the current target and value as of a certain date. My final table for this example would look like this:

```
ClientID | Date         | Value | Target
---------|--------------|-------|--------
63       | 2019-10-04   | 77    |80
63       | 2019-10-05   | 50    |80
63       | 2019-10-06   | 70    |55
63       | 2019-10-07   | 62    |55
67       | 2019-10-04   | 64    |65
67       | 2019-10-05   | 69    |65
67       | 2019-10-06   | 66    |65
```

TIA for any assistance you can offer with this, as I'm relatively new to the SQL world. Also, please let me know if I can further clarify anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lateral `join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t2.clientid = t1.clientid and t2.date <= t1.date
      order by t2.date desc
     ) t2;
```

Comment: Great! Thank you for your fast answer, I will have to mark it correct when the new question timer runs out (LOL). I think the 'top' command was what I was looking for here. I hadn't thought to use it for a most recent date...I've only used it to sample a table. Thanks again!